# profile.d on headless server

Tags: bash, rhel, environment-variables, init-script

Is it a bad idea to put variables needed by a daemon program running at boot on a headless system in `/etc/profile.d/`? From my understanding `profile.d` doesn't get executed until someone logs into the system via an interactive shell. So would my daemon process that will eventually need the system variables held in `profile.d` not have these variables set, until someone logs into the system, or will these be set after `rc.local` runs on an unattended system? (System is RHEL 6.5 running bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad idea if it doesn't work.  I think your concern about `profile.d` not running unless someone logs in is legitimate.

Put an init script in /etc/rc.d/init.d (I think this is the correct directory for Red Hat; in Ubuntu it's /etc/init.d) to start your daemon.  In this script you can declare/define any variables you need and when you start the daemon binary those variables should be in scope.

The link [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442412-managing-linux-daemons-with-init-scripts) explains that process and precisely why it is superior to the `rc.local` method.

The `rc.local` method, mentioned in another answer, won't work because the variables set up in that script are no longer defined when execution returns to Linux INIT.  This is, consequently, before anyone logs in, so it is implicitly before profile.d is run.

Comment: i will try this tomorrow, since my brain is fried from wrapping my head around the linux boot sequence and all. however this is enough info for the answer i was looking for so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, it's only a bad idea if it doesn't work.  So my direct answer is "no", if it doesn't work, "yes" if it works.  Did you try it?  That is, have you confirmed that profile.d doesn't run on your system if no one logs in?

As a suggestion of how to make it work:
Edit the `rc.local` file in the same way, to ensure the settings are applied at boot.

Regardless of what is supposed to happen on a fresh, vanilla install, you should experiment to see if settings you put in either of those files (`profile.d` or `rc.local`) are applied when you expect.  If it just works putting it in `/etc/profile.d`, then it just works, on your setup, lucky you.

[This link](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel6/rhel_6_installation/rhel_6_installation_s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html) from an online-book at linuxtopia suggests that `rc.local` is located at `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` in RHEL 6.

Comment: they are applied when i expect. except i am having trouble closing the gap of what happens after rc.local is executed to when profile.d is executed for how the environment variables are set for the system to use until a user logs in. yes it is in there and has a symbolic link in /etc/rc.local

Comment: I was suggesting to just make the changes in `rc.local` in the first place.  It sounds like you want to boot the machine, but no one logs in, it just runs. Your concern that the profile setup won't be run is legitimate. You know `rc.local` will be run, so just do it there.

Comment: thanks, i did do that for a bootup with a variable needed. So my concern is, if i source the file in profile.d in rc.local, when will those variables be thrown away? if they will be after rc.local is done that is a concern.

Comment: Yes, it seems that once `rc.local` work is done, execution returns to Linux INIT and any variables you set there are gone.

Comment: How is your daemon being started? You should probably hook it into the init routines (start|stop|etc), then you can specify the variables for your daemon in a custom init script.  see [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442412-managing-linux-daemons-with-init-scripts).  The author here shows how to make a custom init script for a daemon and sets env vars in the script.  This is, I think, what happens "in the gap" between `rc.local` and `profile`

Comment: i will look further into doing that. i know that is the correct way but thus have the problem of the loopback needing to be up for a tool my script is using. so if the loopback is not up the two choices i can tell so far are to either have the script fail or have it endlessly way till the loopback comes up but it wont while the script is looping and the networking init scripts never execute and gets stuck in an endless boot loop. then there is also the networking scripts do execute before the daemon script does by some magic and it works perfect. however there is always the risk of failure.